# sorting array with array.sort

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have a listbox and I want to sort each item in that listbox from a-z and assign those code in a button. Do i need to assign the array to the listbox? and then use a loop 
?

This is what I did:

```
protected void sortImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{        
    string[] sort = new string[cartListBox.Items.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < sort.Length; i++)
    {
        sort[i] = cartListBox.Items[i].ToString();
        Array.Sort(sort);
    }
}
```

However, when I click the button, it doesnt do anything.

Comment: you are sorting the string array. Do you expect the list box to be sorted?

Comment: You should sort outside the loop. Also you should sort listbox separately.

Comment: yeah.... do i need to assign the array to the value of the listbox??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sort that outside the loop.

```
protected void sortImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{        
    string[] sort = new string[cartListBox.Items.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < sort.Length; i++)
    {
        sort[i] = cartListBox.Items[i].ToString();
    }
    Array.Sort(sort);

    for (int i = 0; i < sort.Length; i++)
    {
        // reset the order for the cartListBox collection according to the sort array, if needed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ListBox has a [Sorted Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted.aspx) that you can use to enable Sorting

```
cartListBox.Sorted = true;
```

From above MSDN Link:

> Use the Sorted property to automatically sort strings alphabetically in a ListBox. As items are added to a sorted ListBox, the items are moved to the appropriate location in the sorted list. When adding items to a ListBox, it is more efficient to sort the items first and then add new items.
>
> A ListBox with its Sorted set to true should not be bound to data using the DataSource property. To display sorted data in a bound ListBox, you should bind to a data source that supports sorting and have the data source provide the sorting.

Comment: There is a Sorted statement see the link that I added, I also am assuming winforms